# ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE error hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying run two org example on tow different nodes acting as Org1 and Org2. I am able to query chaincode. Next I tried installing composer over it. All the steps were successful except when I tried pinging the network. It gave me ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE error. For Org1-only and Org2-only connection profiles I have used localhost only. Moreover even though there is endorsement failure error, I can see using blockchain explorer and in logs blocks getting generating using ping command in both the machines. Org1 connection profile is given below:

`{
    "name": "byfn-network-org1",
    "type": "hlfv1",
    "mspID": "Org1MSP",
    "peers": [
        {
            "requestURL": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "eventURL": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
            "cert": "/home/user/fabric-samples/multi-org-multi-node/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "eventURL": "grpcs://localhost:8053",
            "cert": "/home/user/fabric-samples/multi-org-multi-node/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer1.org1.example.com"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpcs://<PC2-IP>:9051",
            "cert": "/home/user/fabric-samples/multi-org-multi-node/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer0.org2.example.com"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpcs://<PC2-IP>:10051",
            "cert": "/home/user/fabric-samples/multi-org-multi-node/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer1.org2.example.com"
        }
    ],
    "ca": {
        "url": "https://localhost:7054",
        "name": "ca-org1",
        "cert": "/home/user/fabric-samples/multi-org-multi-node/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt",
        "hostnameOverride": "ca.org1.example.com"
    },
    "orderers": [
        {
            "url" : "grpcs://localhost:7050",
            "cert": "/home/user/fabric-samples/multi-org-multi-node/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt",
            "hostnameOverride": "orderer.example.com"
        }
    ],
    "channel": "mychannel",
    "timeout": 300
}`

Orderer is on PC 1 so I used localhost

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I'm experiencing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The Connection Profiles are used by Composer to connect to the Peer Containers etc, but the Peer Containers (and the Orderer) need to communicate too.  So you need to have address resolution within the Containers.

When you follow the MultiOrg tutorial on a single Machine docker-compose creates a dedicated network bridge that allows all the containers to address and communicate with eachother by fqdn.  When you separate out to 2 Machines you need to manage that.  The `extra_hosts` feature of Docker Compose can help but there are still issues of ports to manage.

The real solution for inter-communicating docker containers on separate machines is to use Kubernetes or Docker Swarm.

Comment: I have connected the two systems using docker swarm. As I have mentioned I am able to run the golang chain codes. But am not sure what addresses shall I give in connection profile. And one more issue , even though endorsement is failed the block is getting generated and replicated in peers of both orgs.