# State database getting updated in spite of endorsement failure in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I was experimenting hyperledger composer on fabric and got an endorsement error. But when I checked the logs even there is mentioned policy failure, the block is getting generated and state database is getting updated[image: endorsement failure log] [image: state db update]

Answer (score 0):

Need more information, context: were you following a specific tutorial? What endorsement policy did you define (contents)? Were you trying out a multi-org setup (was it on the same machine, different machines?). The VSCC error could be for any number of reasons but the main point is your policy is a key factor. Better messaging from Fabric has also been captured -> https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-4164.

Comment: Hi I am using Two org example, and same endorsement policy mentioned there , but the network is on two different systems using docker swarm. The basic chaincodes are running fine but while using composer I am getting endorsement error. This question is continuation of my earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366032/endorsement-policy-failure-error-hyperledger-composer